# Make UnityEvent wait for completion of method calls on listeners?

Tags: unity, c#, events

I am using the UnityEvent EventManager script from this [post](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/events-creating-simple-messaging-system) in one of my games.

I want to know how I can make Unity wait for all the calls to methods on the listeners to finish before moving on to calling the next event?

For example,

If I have a method somewhere in my code that contains:

```
 EventManager.Invoke("MyFirstEvent");
 EventManager.Invoke("MySecondEvent");
```

How can MySecondEvent be invoked only after all the listeners of MyFirstEvent have finished ?

The reason being that I perform an operation in one of the listeners of MyFirstEvent which is needed for an operation performed in MySecondEvent.

Alternatively am I best to use a coroutine and call the MyFirstEvent on the first frame and MySecondEvent on the following one just to be sure. I read that spawning costly actions over a few frames can reduce spikes in CPU usage. However is it best practice to do so, or is it likely to cause problems down the line ?

Thanks

Comment: You'd need your objects to send an event back that they have finished. And handle your second event when it's triggered. You'd have to keep track of count ( if you need all of them to finish first ). But you might want to consider going back to the drawing board if this gets too complicated.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is I've got a working version so far but it is very messy. the game is tile based and I do most of the logic in a Tile class I created. I would like to move away from that, so that I can bolt on additional mechanics, such as gems and spells. I was thinking of using a TileManager, a GemManager and a SpellManager and have them completely independent and communication only with the GameManager, who would be in charge of recording player interactions and casting events to the other managers.

Comment: sounds like a good setup but don't try to coddle your game with tons of managers. You're using Unity after all so thinking in self contained components is a good idea too. What if you decide to not give your unit a spell ability but something else like melee? Are you going to write a manager for that too?

Comment: You are misusing events. Events are not intended to be "orderable". Events just happen. Writing code that depends on how long it takes to process the event or even when the event is processed is not part of the paradigm. If you need to order events then you should create a 3rd class that controls the ordering.

Comment: Thanks I added this in a method on my game manager. I call a coroutine which triggers an `TurnEnded` and `TurnStarted` event on different frames. That has the advantage of also spreading the calculations required to set up a new turn on a couple of frames.